# RPL BR routes limit?

Tags: c, ipv6, sensors, contiki

I'm developing a Contiki+Cooja application(sky motes) with one border router and about 30 motes.
For some of them I'm simulating a direct cable connection by putting them in the tx range of the BR(in cooja) and setting: #define  DUIP_CONF_IPV6_RPL    0
I have noticed that querying the br (http://[aaaa::212:7401:1:101]) for neighbors and routes, I received always maximum 20 routes (not always the same).
The routes not in the list are not reachable.
There is a particular reason for receiving only 20 routes?
Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

The number of max. routes is configurable. 20 is the default. See https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/contiki-default-conf.h#L154

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it is necessary to add i the project.conf related to the border router

```
#undef NBR_TABLE_CONF_MAX_NEIGHBORS
#define NBR_TABLE_CONF_MAX_NEIGHBORS 40
#undef UIP_CONF_MAX_ROUTES
#define UIP_CONF_MAX_ROUTES 40
```

where 40 is the new value

Answer (score 0):

You can change the configuration in project.conf file. With Cooja simulation and z1 mote, in my case max routes is 50